# Unit testing with TwiP ant Powermock

Tags: java, unit-testing

In my unit tests, I use both [TwiP](http://twip.sourceforge.net/) and [PowerMock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/). Both are great tools, but both require the test to be run with their own runner, such as this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) 
public class MyTest {
…
}
```

Is it possible – and if so, how – to combine the two? Perhaps by creating a custom runner or something along the lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible, check out the PowerMock [rule](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/PowerMockRule).

Comment: Thank you for this pointer. Not only can I now combine TwiP and PowerMock, I also learned something new about JUnit that I had overlooked.